# DTD syntax - allow sub element OR pcdata

Tags: xml, dtd, pcdata

My .xml structure may have the following data:

```
<entry id="one-string">
            <class>nmWinMultiReports_main</class>
            <classParams>string</classParams>
         </entry>
<entry id="multiple-elements">
            <class>nmJavaScript_main</class>
            <classParams>
               <pluginid>monitorPlugin</pluginid>
               <bla>string</bla>
               <tag>abc</tag>
            </classParams>
         </entry>
```

How do I define the .dtd file to allow `classParams` to either 1. be a string or 2. multiple sub elements (each once)?

I tried:

> ```
> <!ELEMENT class ( #PCDATA ) >
> <!ELEMENT classParams ( #PCDATA | pluginid | bla | tag ) >
>          <!ELEMENT pluginid ( #PCDATA ) >
>          <!ELEMENT bla ( #PCDATA ) >
>          <!ELEMENT tag ( #PCDATA ) >
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made it:

```
<!ELEMENT classParams ( #PCDATA | pluginid | bla | tag )* >
```

Comment: Useful. Any idea why this one works and the other doesn't? Is it actually doing what it looks like it's doing?

Answer (score 2):

DTDs cannot enforce the constraint you describe; the easiest way to get something like that constraint is to add a new element (call it `string`) and declare classParams as taking either `string` or the sequence of `pluginid` etc. as children:

```
<!ELEMENT string (#PCDATA) >
<!ELEMENT classParams (string 
                      | (pluginid, bla, tag))
>
```

Alternatively, if

```
<classParams><string>foo</string></classParams>
```

seems too heavy, you could declare `entry` as taking either `classParams` or `classParamString` as content:

```
<!ELEMENT entry (class, (classParams | classParamString)) >
<!ELEMENT classParamString (#PCDATA) >
<!ELEMENT classParams (pluginid, bla, tag) >
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am currently using my construct but will possibly use your approach in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by this way as well:

```
<!ELEMENT classParams ANY>
```

Comment: Could you please add more details about the solution you provide?